# How can I get Pika to retry connecting to RabbitMQ if it fails the first time?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to get my program, which uses Pika, to continually retry connecting to RabbitMQ on failure. From what I've seen of the Pika docs, there's a SimpleReconnectionStrategy class that can be used to accompish this but it doesn't seem to be working very well.

```
strategy        = pika.SimpleReconnectionStrategy()
parameters      = pika.ConnectionParameters(server)

self.connection = pika.AsyncoreConnection(parameters, True, strategy)
self.channel    = self.connection.channel()
```

The connection should `wait_for_open` and setup the reconnection strategy.

However, when I run this, I get the following errors thrown:

```
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <pika.asyncore_adapter.RabbitDispatcher at 0xb6ba040c> (<class 'socket.error'>:[Errno 111] Connection refused [/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|read|79] [/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|435] [/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|handle_connect_event|443])
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <pika.asyncore_adapter.RabbitDispatcher at 0xb6ba060c> (<class 'socket.error'>:[Errno 111] Connection refused [/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|read|79] [/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|435] [/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|handle_connect_event|443])
```

These errors are continually thrown whilst Pika tries to connect. If I start the RabbitMQ server while my client is running, it will connect. I just don't like the sight of these errors... Are they normal? Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3):

```
import socket

...

while True:
    connectSucceeded = False
    try:
        self.channel    = self.connection.channel()
        connectSucceeded = True
    except socket.error:
        pass
    if connectSucceeded:
        break
```

Something like the above is usually used. You could also add `time.sleep()` every time through the loop to try less frequently because sometimes servers do go down. In real production code I would also count the number of retries (or track the amount of time spent retrying) and give up after some interval. Sometimes it is better to log an error and crash.